# Why doesn't 'sudo cp' copy files in the /sys directory?

Tags: sudo, cp

I want to make an exact copy of the `/sys` directory, and tried the following command:

```
sudo cp -ra /sys ~/Documents/dir1
```

It does not work as I expected... I get a lot of error messages such as:

```
cp: error reading '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.force_empty': Invalid argument
cp: error reading '/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/power/autosuspend_delay_ms': Input/output error
cp: cannot open '/sys/devices/system/clockevents/clockevent0/unbind_device' for reading: Permission denied
cp: error reading '/sys/devices/virtual/block/loop0/trace/enable': No such device or address
```

Why isn't `sudo` enough to make `cp` copy every file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/sys` directory isn't a normal directory, but instead a "virtual" one. From "[The Linux Filesystem Explained](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/linux-filesystem-explained/)":

> /sys
>
> /sys is another virtual directory like /proc and /dev and also
> contains information from devices connected to your computer.
>
> In some cases you can also manipulate those devices. I can, for
> example, change the brightness of the screen of my laptop by modifying
> the value stored in the
> /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
> file (on your machine you will probably have a different file). But to
> do that you have to become superuser. The reason for that is, as with
> so many other virtual directories, messing with the contents and files
> in /sys can be dangerous and you can trash your system. DO NOT TOUCH
> until you are sure you know what you are doing.

Similar directories are `/dev`, `/proc` and `/run`.

Since files in these directories are created, changed and removed all the time while the system is running, it doesn't make any sense to copy them.

Think more of these directories as a *dynamic snapshot* of the current state of the system, rather than a *static medium* of storage.

The reason you get errors even with `sudo` is probably that the files are either fully locked or removed by the system before the `cp` command could take effect.

Comment: What should be done with such directories when I try to make a copy of an Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Hello Take a look at man dd

Comment: @rapt ...nothing

Comment: @WU-TANG Your reply probably depends on the method of copying, since `cp` causes errors.

Comment: @rapt I dont think you're reading Artur Meinild's answer carefully enough or you are just disregarding what he is saying. There is nothing to be done. When you make an exact clone of the car sitting in your driveway, how are you going to copy the song that is playing on the radio????? No method of copying is going to make any difference in the final product(in this case). Even if you found a way to capture that song, the radio will be "populated" with the current song when you turn it on. And cp doesn't "cause" errors, there is just essentially 'nothing' for cp to copy, so cp throws an error.

Comment: @WU-TANG It was easy to have a basic understanding of why `cp` won't work well with `/sys`. My comment to you meant that if for example I want to make a copy of an ubuntu installation by `cp / /media/external-usb/my-ubuntu-backup` then `cp` gives errors. Other commands like `dd` that was mentioned here might not give errors (I have not tried yet), but `dd` seems to overwrite the whole destination partition: not fun. So if I want to backup my ubuntu installation, I either need to exclude those dirs/files that are virtual, or use a more suitable command. This is not as easy as "nothing", for me.

Comment: @rapt First, you don't do a copy of Ubuntu installation using `cp`. You'll mostly probably lose permissions, symlinks, hardlinks, devices and all importants stuff. If you want to backup your root partition, use `tar`, not `cp`. This will do a copy of an actual filesystem, not all kinds of virtual stuff. Second, you do it after booting from a **live medium**, not from your installed system. Your installed system should be **inactive** if you want to make a copy of it. This way there will be no issue of `/sys` directory.

Comment: @raj Okay, thanks for the tips. I saw the `tar` option earlier today but thought it was less straightforward than other commands. I will look into it. My ubuntu installation dirs are mounted on several partitions across several disks, will I have to make a separate tar for each partition, or is it possible to come up with a single tar?

Comment: 2 things: "Copying a system" via cp is a bit "odd", (sorry i don't know how else to say it). If you want to take that science project on; if there's levels of depth below /proc, /sys, /run,etc that is necessary to copy... well good luck figuring that out. I wouldnt be willing to try figure that beyond the base directory. There is cloning software for this. 2nd You wouldn't use dd to copy "pieces" of your install, you'd use it to copy the entire install(drive/partitions) to their target. Though I have dd'd running systems and it worked, it's probably better they be inactive as raj pointed out

Comment: @rapt You should do a separate tar for each partition. I used this method many times to clone installations from one machine to the other (of course, after cloning several things need to be adjusted on the target machine before the system will boot).

Comment: @raj I've tried cp, tar, rsync (with certain options and adjustments). I did not see much difference in the end result, but there was a difference in how long it took. In each case, I had to exclude (or not include) the virtual directories discussed above.

Comment: @rapt did you tell tar to archive a single filesystem only? And did you do it from a live session as I suggested, and on each partition separately?

Comment: @jar With tar, I used ideas I found in other questions, that used tar to send the output into a pipe, and then use tar to read the input from the pipe and write it to the destination. Doing it like that, tar was the fastest, comparing with cp and rsync. So in the destination there is no one tar file but a copy of the original directory. This way it's faster to sync and search. And it lets you copy several partitions into one directory tree. I could do it with the actual installation active, without booting from a flash drive. Only had to exclude virtual directories.

Comment: @jar So the fastest way to copy I found, was to write and read to a pipe with tar, and then rsync the source and destination to update files that tar did not copy for some reason. In future backups if there are no huge differences since last backup, you can just do the rsync step.