Ubuntu 24.04 dual boot deep sleep not working
I have a work computer with the following specs:

Dell Precision 3490
Intel Core Ultra 7 155H
Dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04
Kernel version 6.8.0 (most recent one running without problems)

I am unable to enter deep sleep. The output of cat /sys/power/mem_sleep is just s2idle. I have tried the steps described in this issue, however without success. On the windows side the suspend (and even hibernation) works without any problem.
I know this is quite a specific issue but if anyone has any suggestions of things that could fix this, I would be very grateful. Turning the machine off every time is just really annoying.
Thank you for your help!

I have the same exact issue!
I am running Ubuntu 24.10, thus running Linux 6.11. (I don't believe this issue to be specific to a version of Ubuntu or Linux).
My hardware is a Samsung Galaxy Book 4, Intel Core 150U. (I also don't believe it is a hardware specific issue).
From googling around, I get a sense this issue is a problem with dual boot (somehow, I just can't tell how or why). I suspect if we didn't have dual boot, so just a Ubuntu install, the deep suspend would work. (I just don't want to get rid of Windows for dev testing purposes ugh)
Thanks for posting @vinikay

Maybe this other post can be of help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469680/how-to-change-sys-power-mem-sleep-nothing-is-able-to-change-it-and-all-advice

unfortunately, it didn't help me, as my BIOS doesn't seem to have a power sleep state config option :(
